# Started Account in Heroku... public or private repositories?

Tags: git, heroku

It's correct to affirm that Heroku provides **private** repositories **for started account**? Or are those repositories public?

Comment: They're private, but you can grant exactly who has access in the `Collaborators` tab..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repositories are private to the app owner and any [collaborators](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/collab).